# Transform requests of url with no www string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to make my default url in rails application respond the cdn without www, like my-domain.com. I tried override the default_url as below:

```
def default_url_options
    if Rails.env.production?
      {:host => "cdn.com"}
    else  
      {}
    end
 end
```

But this solution doesn't work to the ssl connections. In my .htaccess I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(my-domain\.com)(:443)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://my-domain/$1 [R=301,L]
order deny,allow
```

But when I  request the url: https://www.my-domain.com/, the browser yet call the same url with www.
The problem is that the ssl certificated is valid to the my-domain.com no the www string, and when I request the the url like this: https://www.my-domain.com/, the Chrome  inform that the ssl is not valid. I need some way in the rail application to transform all requests: https://www.my-domain.com/ in https://my-domain.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try this .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(my-domain\.com)(:443)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://my-domain/$1 [R=301,L]
order deny,allow
```

notice how there is another token, `(www)?` in the front? It matches your domain name if your have www in front or not.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks very much to your attention. I used this  rewrite and dosen't work. My application uses apache with Thin. I believe this kind of configuration should be  at level of rails framework. Because when a user clicks the  sing_up link, for example, the rail forces the ssl connection and builds the url with www.my-domain.com. Do you have some idea?
Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgor to put the dot after the www in `^(www)(my-domain...` so I couldn't work. (it would have rewritten `wwwmy-domain` to `mydomain`, but not with a dot in between. I have corrected my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Also, i don't think that you should remedy this issue with your framework: Or rather, if you did, you would have to do exactly the same as this rewrite rule does: find out if you are on a https encrypted connection, if not: redirect to http://my-domain.com